# Installing Helios on UBUNTU

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

Complete Noob at UBUNTU, but..

I have got an UBUNTU server from backspace and I have installed Ruby 2.0

so ruby -V gives me version 2.0

I am now trying to install Helios with

```
get install helios
```

and i get the usual :

```
ERROR:  Error installing helios:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

the file is libpq-fe.h and it cannot find it, but after searching it says this file is from Postgres and I have followed the ubuntu installation of postgres and i have installed the client and the server.

So I am completely lost.

Comment: The error message says what you need to do: "You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application."

Comment: "Complete noob at Ubuntu"? Buy a 200 netbook, paint Ubuntu onto a flash drive, boot off it, and put a real Ubuntu home server at your fingertips, before messing with a remote one!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `libpq-dev` PostGre library:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: And thanks Uri Agassi of course for pointing me to the right direction.